# Вывод Toast из сервиса в Андроид 11 и 12

Tags: java, android, android-toast

Появилась проблема, нужно вывести свой toast из сервиса (без activity) в API R и S. использую след. код

```
LayoutInflater myInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
View view = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.new_toast, null);
Toast mytoast = new Toast(context);
TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id._toast_text);
textView.setText(message_toast);

ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.image_list);
if (bitmap != 0) {
    imageView.setImageBitmap(roundCorner(context, 48, 0,
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), bitmap),
            (int) (15 * scale)));
}
mytoast.setView(view);
mytoast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
mytoast.show();
```

Если при запущенном activity toast выводится, то без него - нет.
Ругается на null во второй строке, и зачеркивает строчку

```
mytoast.setView(view);
```

Как мне вывести мой toast без activity?

P.S. Это фишка Андроид 11 и выше. Но всё же, может есть обход

Comment: раньше и АлертДиалог выводился без активити. p.s. удивлен, что только в 11-ой версии это изменили. почему бы вам просто не обновлять Notification ?

Comment: Он есть, но он не нужен особо

Comment: Из какого потока траст показываете? Возможно он не работает при показе не из главного потока

Comment: Пробовал использовать new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post. Но аналогично

Answer (score 0):

Из выше указанного кода я увидел следующую строку `textView.setText(message_toast);`
Но что вы передаёте и как вы передаёте сам `message_toast` мне не понятно. Для начала попробуйте указать `textView.setText("message_toast");` или так `textView.setText(R.string.message_toast);`
А в файл string.xml добавить строку с именем `message_toast` и с значением вашего тоста.

Comment: Это вырезка из процедуры, куда передаются параметры